# Does this sentence using も twice say that the speaker doesn't have 女子力?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I am participating in a relay manga through a university student group in Japan, and the previous member's contributed pages to the manga about a 女子力バトル introduced a sole male character who seems to be a team member in the competition.  I need to draw the next section of the manga.

The captain of the opposing team protests his appearance by saying, 「そっちだって男がまざってんじゃん。」

The next speech bubble is not clear as to which of the two characters is speaking, either the male or the opposing team's captain.
It says,

「女子力もクソもねーだろ。」

Is the male character replying to her that he doesn't have 女子力?  (Does ねー mean ない?)
Is it possibly the captain accusing him of not having 女子力?
Or do the も have another meaning?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think XXもくそもない = XXもへったくれもない. http://home.alc.co.jp/db/owa/s_htsrv_rep4?num_in=5876&char_in=06&char2_in=he

Comment: 「Aもクソもない。」 = "A is totally out of the question!"

Comment: @TokyoNagoya それ、コメでなく回答欄に、是非！

Comment: "out of the question"と「くそ」の汚さと強さは、ちょっと違う気がするんですけど…あのalcリンクの英訳例も怪しいと思います。チラッとみたところで、例文の「～本物もへったくれも」とは、そんな安物にまず「本物」かどうかは問題外、と解釈したのですけれど、外れかな。もしその解釈が正しいなら、その英訳もちょっと違うと思います。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From simplest to most complex:

1. ねー is a vulgar bend of ない.
2. The first も is that sort of emphatic 'even' you may know, like 今年の夏、雨は一滴も降らなかった (there was not even a single drop of rain this summer)
3. ~もクソも is an extreme comparator, indicating that whatever applies to the previous one, also applies to shit. I believe it comes from [「味噌も糞も一緒だ」](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%91%B3%E5%99%8C%E3%82%82%E7%B3%9E%E3%82%82%E4%B8%80%E7%B7%92) which means that between two things, one good and the other bad, there isn't very much difference at all.

It sounds like a continuation from the rival captain's first line. "You even got a dude mixed in there. Your girl power ain't *shit*."